# how to return null if MySQL returned an empty result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

i use this script

```
SELECT ti_556, TIME_FORMAT(`waktu_be5b`, '%H:%i')  
FROM be5b 
WHERE waktu_be5b >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY  
 AND waktu_be5b <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00')
limit 1
```

how to return null if no data match with this condition?

i try using COALESCE

```
 SELECT coalesce(ti_556,null), TIME_FORMAT(`waktu_be5b`, '%H:%i')
 FROM be5b WHERE waktu_be5b >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY
    AND waktu_be5b <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00')
 limit 1
```

and the output

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0006 sec )

Comment: COALESCE just modifies the field value in the returned row(s), it's of no use if your recordset has no rows. I'm not even convinced mysql can do what you want (in Postgres you'd use a custom plpgsql function that tests your rowcount then adds a row if it's 0)

Comment: so, if no rows, what should i use?

Comment: Well I did some quick research and mysql does support stored proceedures so you can do it

Comment: In this case, I think you need to check result set has tuples. in PHP mysql_num_rows() is for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a union that is mutual exclusive:

```
SELECT ti_556, TIME_FORMAT(`waktu_be5b`, '%H:%i')  
FROM be5b
WHERE waktu_be5b >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY
AND waktu_be5b <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00') limit 1
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL
FROM (SELECT 1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM be5b
    WHERE waktu_be5b >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY
    AND waktu_be5b <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00')
)
```

Only one side of the union can return data
.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM be5b WHERE waktu_be5b &gt;= DATE_FO' at line 7

Comment: Your SQL solves the problem but is VERY complex, if it takes 2s to process one query, the other will take also 2s (or more) and will overall double the processing time - so I don't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really up on mysql syntax so this may not work, but it should be close:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN

  SELECT ti_556, TIME_FORMAT(`waktu_be5b`, '%H:%i')  
  INTO temp_table
  FROM be5b
  WHERE waktu_be5b >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00') + INTERVAL -1 DAY
  AND waktu_be5b <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 01:00:00') LIMIT 1;

  SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;

  IF(num_rows = 0) THEN
       INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (NULL,NULL);
  END IF;

  SELECT * FROM temp_table;
END
```

You'll probably want to pass in your own args as well.